# Filtering the point cloud coming from multiple lidars

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

I have been experimenting with the pcl point cloud library. I have  point cloud data coming from 3 different lidars. I filter out the point cloud for each lidar to remove unwanted points in their local frame around each lidar. Then I transform it to map and combine all the points. I noticed that still some point cloud from other lidars appear on the adjusent lidar area as noise. How do I remove those?

For the filtering part, I used passthrough filter from pcl and ROS.

Comment: Sounds like your transform isn't 100% correct, or your lidars relative positions do actually change. Not really much people can help you with, without further info like what are you trying to accomplish, what does noise look like, what have you tried, etc.